# select multiple items like inline list only with CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, drop-down-menu

Can we implement multi select options like inline forms (without pressing CTRL button) (see image) *only* in CSS? Several web css frameworks, like [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#multiple-select), do but they use Javascript.

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple
This one uses native multiple select dropdown, but you need to use ctrl button to select multiple values, so its not really possible without javascript, but you can use checkboxes and tweak them by making them look like dropdown values, but in the end you do need javascript to show the selected values at top

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this with checkboxes.  Here's a basic list I made for you.

```css
ul {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes">
  <label>Choose some boxes</label>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 4</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 5</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 6</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 7</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> checkbox 8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: Here's a very fancy way of doing what I just did. I found this example on this guy's blog: https://codersblock.com/blog/checkbox-trickery-with-css/

I put it into a jsfiddle for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/c0fy4xrj/